# Make Hibernate drop or update old Index

Tags: mysql, hibernate, tomcat

I've been experimenting with different Indexes on one of my tables. I appears that Hibernate will only add an index if it does not already exist by name. This is potentially a problem. If you've applied an index, it won't be replaced if you change the columns it uses, and if you remove an index in code, it will remain in the database.

Are my assertions correct about how Hibernate handles indexes? Is there a recommendation for managing indexes with Hibernate?

Example situation:

I had these indexes on a table:

```
@Index(name = "evententry_comp2_idx", columnList = "document, objectId, project, documentType, action, objectType, eventDate"),
@Index(name = "evententry_comp3_idx", columnList = "objectId, documentType, action, objectType, eventDate")
```

But then I changed them to this:

```
@Index(name = "evententry_comp2_idx", columnList = "objectId, documentType, action, objectType")
```

So in code, evententry_comp2_idx removed some columns and evententry_comp3_idx was removed altogether. However, after rebooting tomcat after this change, both indexes remained the same. It appears that these indexes must be removed manually in the database and new indexes must be created if you want to change an old one.

Thanks!